# why am i seeing this error even though my build is successful

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

while bitbake core-image-sato, i am getting this ERROR: Invalid value in BB_DISKMON_DIRS:   Disk space monitor will NOT be enable

NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 6417 tasks of which 6417 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.

Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.

how to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set the variable `BB_DISKMON_DIRS` to an invalid value. This variable allows you to monitor how much space is left on the disk of your build machine, and to take action in case the disk gets too full.

The syntax is as follows:

```
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "<action>,<dir>,<threshold>[ <action>,<dir>,<threshold>][ ...]
```

This executes the `action` (warn, stop tasks or abort) when the `dir` (your chosen directory) gets below the chosen `threshold` (`<free space>,<free inodes>`). You can define as many actions as you want.

Source: [BitBake Variable Glossary](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/dev/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-BB_DISKMON_DIRS)

If you can't find the location where you set this variable, you might try to find it with `bitbake -e core-image-sato | grep BB_DISKMON_DIRS=`